# iOS switch ViewControllers of same data hierarchy

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitoolbar

I struggle on the concept of an app. There is basically a ViewController for data input. The base ViewController has an embedded NavigationController to provide a ToolBar. The Toolbar is supposed to have three buttons to open other ViewControllers presenting the same input data differently.
My question now is what concept do I need to use to be able to start each ViewController (1-3) from the base ViewController and to make it possible to switch between the ViewControllers at the last Hierarchy Level.

I know how to call ViewControllers but how do I implement an additional Toolbar in ViewController 1-3 for switching between the VC 1-3 (another Navigation Controller?)? And how do I make sure that VC 1-3 are not dismissed and reopend again when switching between VC 1-3? How would all open VCs (1-3) closed (dismissed) once the base ViewController is called again by the user?

I try to find some helpful answers in the Apple [doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH111-SW1) but I failed so far.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Why not use a uitabbar controller? It seems to do everything you need it to. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I forgot to say that the base ViewController and its NavigationController is part of an TabBarController already. Using another on would look kind of odd to the user.

Comment: Does `UIPageViewController` fit your image of how it should work?